# Does Al Arabiya have a presence in the US? And if so, was there any effort to list them a a foreign agent?

Tags: united-states, media, saudi-arabia, foreign-interference, united-arab-emirates

Related to [my question on Al Jazeera](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46858/has-the-doj-taken-any-steps-to-list-al-jazeera-as-a-foreign-agent), does its UAE-based competitor 
[Al Arabiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Arabiya) have a presence in the US? And if it does, have there been any efforts, e.g. Congressional opinions on having them listed as a foreign agent under FARA?

According to Wikipedia

> Through [its parent company] MBC, Saudi Prince Abdulaziz bin Fahd and his maternal uncle Waleed bin Ibrahim al Ibrahim own and have control over Al Arabiya.

Answer (score 1):

(partial answer)

> Does Al Arabiya have a presence in the US?

Yes, they appear to have a Washington bureau chief and [they interviewed (short clip by the AP)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAnQASZS-70) the then just elected President Barrack Obama. From [Al Arabiya's own website](https://www.alarabiya.net/articles/2009/01/28/65189.html):

> "We contacted many of our friends inside and outside the American administration," Melham told AlArabiya.net. "And I believe there have been discussions in the White House about whether the new president should now approach the situation in the Muslim world especially after closing Guantanamo and starting the withdrawal from Iraq. They later informed me that the first interview will be given to Al Arabiya and to me personally."
>
> The White House contacted Melhem, Al Arabiya’s Washington bureau chief, and asked him not to announce the interview until an official announcement was made by the administration. The interview was to take place after Obama's meeting with his Middle East peace envoy Sen. George Mitchell and his Secretary of State Hillary Clinton.